# Photo lens only searches one subfolder

Tags: unity, lenses

On my computer (running Ubuntu 14.04) Unity's photo lens only searches one subfolder of my Pictures folder.

The strange thing is that there is nothing special about that folder. My photos are organized in folders by year and month in folders named like this:

~/Pictures/Share/yyyy/yyyy-mm/

The photo lens only searches subfolder 2013/2013-06, but not 2013/2013-05 nor 2013/2013-07 nor anything else. The permissions on the searched folder are not different from other folders.

Why might be? What can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: Execute `killall unity-lens-photos` and`/usr/lib/unity-lens-photos/unity-lens-photos` then do a search and add the output in the terminal to your post.

Comment: I have no process called `unity-lens-photos` running, and I have no file or directory named `/usr/lib/unity-lens-photos`. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by doing a search that produces output in a terminal.

Comment: Without `unity-lens-photos` there should be no photo search at all in dash. Run `sudo apt-get install unity-lens-photos`.

Comment: `unity-lens-photos` is installed. If I run `dpkg -L unity-lens-photos` it lists a number of files and directories, but `/usr/lib/unity-lens-photos` is not one of them. Anyway, as you can see below, you were right about the problem with importing into shotwell. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photo lens only searches pictures imported in `shotwell` and some online apps.
If you got only the `2013/2013-06` folder imported there it won't search other folders.
If you import the other folders as well your problem should be gone.

Comment: You nailed it! I had only imported 2013/2013-06 in shotwell. Thank you. Ill will award the bounty as soon as I am able to.

Comment: Glad I could help!